# Add lastprice to all the rows with higher idexchangeplatform when idrequest and idpair are same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'price' with the following rows

```
idRequest | idPair | idExchangePlatform | lastPrice
    1         1               1               95
    1         1               2               100
    1         1               3               40
    2         1               1               80
    2         1               2               250
    2         1               3               10
    3         1               1               110
    3         1               2               300
    3         1               3               60
    1         2               2               800
    1         2               3               1300
    2         2               2               1110
    2         2               3               1950
```

i need to make a SELECT QUERY WHERE idRequest and exchangePair match with the same table values but different idExchangePlatform

For example for this set of values:

```
idRequest | idPair | idExchangePlatform | lastPrice
    1         1               1               95
    1         1               2               100
    1         1               3               40
```

i need to get the following output:

```
idRequest | idPair | idEP_a | idEP_b | lastPrice_sum
    1         1         1       2           195
    1         1         1       3           135
    1         1         2       3           140
```

i'm using this query but it duplicates the result because is matching the idExchangePlatform in twisted order.

```
select p1.idRequest, p1.idPair, p1.idExchangePlatform AS idEP_a, p2.idExchangePlatform AS idEP_b, (p1.lastPrice + p2.lastPrice) AS lastPrice_sum
from price as p1
JOIN price AS p2
ON p1.idRequest = p2.idRequest AND p1.idPair = p2.idPair AND p1.idExchangePlatform <> p2.idExchangePatform;
```

This is the output i get from this query:

```
idRequest | idPair | idEP_a | idEP_b | lastPrice_sum
    1         1         1       2           195
    1         1         1       3           135
    1         1         2       3           140
    1         1         2       1           195
    1         1         3       1           135
    1         1         3       2           140
```

Is there a way to prevent this with some CLAUSE?

Comment: Maybe instead of `p1.idExchangePlatform <> p2.idExchangePatform`, how about `p1.idExchangePlatform < p2.idExchangePatform`?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema:

```
     create table price(idRequest int,  idPair int, idExchangePlatform int,  lastPrice int);
     insert into price values(1,         1,               1,               95);
     insert into price values(1,         1,               2,               100);
     insert into price values(1,         1,               3,               40);
     insert into price values(2,         1,               1,               80);
     insert into price values(2,         1,               2,               250);
     insert into price values(2,         1,               3,               10);
     insert into price values(3,         1,               1,               110);
     insert into price values(3,         1,               2,               300);
     insert into price values(3,         1,               3,               60);
     insert into price values(1,         2,               2,               800);
     insert into price values(1,         2,               3,               1300);
     insert into price values(2,         2,               2,               1110);
     insert into price values(2,         2,               3,               1950);
```

Query:

```
 select  p1.idRequest, p1.idPair, p1.idExchangePlatform AS idEP_a, p2.idExchangePlatform AS idEP_b,  (p1.lastPrice + p2.lastPrice) AS lastPrice_sum
 from price p1
 inner join price p2
 ON p1.idRequest = p2.idRequest and p1.idRequest=p1.idPair
 AND p1.idPair = p2.idPair AND p1.idExchangePlatform < p2.idExchangePlatform;
```

Output:

| idRequest | idPair | idEP_a | idEP_b | lastPrice_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 195 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 140 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 135 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3060 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac946158638e39264b6fc31ad5099d1d)*

Comment: Is thsi the query you are looking for?